# How can select tags be indexed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**HTML:**

```
<select class="selectExample"> (...) </select>
<select class="selectExample"> (...) </select>
<select class="selectExample"> (...) </select>
<select class="selectExample"> (...) </select>
```

**Script**:

```
$(".selectExample")[3].hide()
```

It gives me an error, saying it's not a function.
Then I read...

> Do it with a span around the select!

And, exactly, that's a good way to hide(). But, in my case, I want to do this;

```
$('selectExample > option').each(function() {
```

And I can't do that with the span, since the options are children of the select.
 I just want to know how to do

```
$('selectExample[i] > option').each(function() {
```

Comment: `$(".selectExample").eq(3).hide()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `[]` returns reference of underlying DOM element and they doesn't have access to jQuery methods the error arise.

Use [`.eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) method /[`:eq()` selector](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) instead of `[]`

```
$(".selectExample").eq(3).hide();
$(".selectExample:eq(3)").hide()
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. You saved me. :)

Answer (score 0):

To get select element using JavaScript:

```
var selects = document.querySelectorAll('.selectExample'); // this will return the list of elements

// to hide specific element we can use index (0 based index)
selects[2].style.display = 'none';

//to get the options
var options = selects[2].options;
```

Iterating options you can use `$.each()` loop or normal JavaScript `for` loop.

**jQuery:**

```
$.each(options, function(i, opt) {
 .....
});
```

**JavaScript:**

```
for(var i = 0 ; i< options.length; i++) {
  .....
  var opt = options[i];
}
```